# How to carry forward a certain Value of Record to the next record without an APEX code

Tags: workflow, process-builder, object, sum

I have an instance of an Object, which has the variables

```
type = x, number_of_exams = 2, previous_no_of_exams = 0.
```

In the next instance of the object, of the same **type = x**, I want the **previous_no_of_exams** to be = to 2, **number_of_exams = 0**.

So when an instance of the same object is created, I want it to check any previous record of that object, **type 'x'** and get the **number_of_exams** value and assign it to the new object instance's **previous_no_of_exams** variable.

Can this be done without APEX or triggers?.

Maybe through workflows or process automation?

Comment: How you distinguish which object is "previous" ?

Comment: can we check, if the same type of object exist before hand, like a before trigger does. but without a trigger?

Comment: You could have a look at Visual Flows, they allow querying of other objects.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried storing these variables in a custom setting? I believe you can store those "counter" type variables and then update from process builder if you're trying to keep an active count of how many records have been created / updated.